Perl DB_File Query Key is not working but key exist
I'm new with perl.
I'm writing a little code to lookup value in db from key.
If I do a loop on the %hash for keys and value : I can see my keys and my values.
But, when I want to load a specific key, the value is empty.
$database_obj = tie(%db_hash, 'DB_File', $database_name,
                            O_RDONLY, 0644, $DB_HASH) ||
                 fatal_exit "Cannot open database %s: $!", $database_name;

# This work - Console display [myKey1]: {myVal1} ...
while (my ($key, $val) = each(%db_hash))
        { print "[$key]: {$val}\n"; }

# but, this doesn't work - $value is empty - I want to get myVal1
$value = $db_hash{myKey1};


db_dump show this header :
VERSION=3
format=bytevalue
type=hash
h_nelem=4098
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END

If anyone can help me ? Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Yannick
I have try to manipulate the key format with or without quote.

Additionnal test 1
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DB_File;
use Fcntl;
use Sys::Syslog qw(:DEFAULT setlogsock);

my ($database_obj, %db_hash);
my $database_name="./mydb.db";

$database_obj = tie(%db_hash, 'DB_File', $database_name,
                            O_RDONLY, 0644, $DB_HASH) ||
                 print "Cannot open database %s: $!", $database_name;

print "DUMP ...\n";
while (my ($key, $val) = each(%db_hash))
        { print "[$key]: {$val}\n"; }


my $search="mykey.1";
print "ONLY $search\n";
my $value = $db_hash{$search};
print "Value: $value\n" unless $value;

Result:
DUMP ...
[mykey.1]: {myVal1;myVal-1}
[mykey.2]: {myval2}
ONLY mykey.1
Use of uninitialized value $value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 25.
Value:

keys and values can contains . -> it seems a problem ?

Additionnal test 2
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DB_File;
use Fcntl;
use Sys::Syslog qw(:DEFAULT setlogsock);
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;

my ($database_obj, %db_hash);
my $database_name="./mydb.db";

$database_obj = tie(%db_hash, 'DB_File', $database_name,
                            O_RDONLY, 0644, $DB_HASH) ||
                 print "Cannot open database %s: $!", $database_name;

#print "DUMP ...\n";
# while (my ($key, $val) = each(%db_hash))
#        { print "[$key]: {$val}\n"; }

print Dumper \%db_hash;

my $search="mykey.1";
print "ONLY $search\n";
my $value = $db_hash{"$search"};
print "Value: $value\n" unless $value;

result:
$VAR1 = {
          "mykey.1\0" => "myVal1;myVal-1\0",
          "mykey.2\0" => "myval2\0"
        };


Sorry for delay, but it seems that we are not in the same timezone.
Data are populated with postmap
I see that my strings are terminated with \0 (null terminator ?), so I try to add it in the lookup.
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DB_File;
use Fcntl;
use Sys::Syslog qw(:DEFAULT setlogsock);
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;

my ($database_obj, %db_hash);
my $database_name="./mydb.db";

$database_obj = tie(%db_hash, 'DB_File', $database_name,
                            O_RDONLY, 0644, $DB_HASH) ||
                 print "Cannot open database %s: $!", $database_name;

#print "DUMP ...\n";
# while (my ($key, $val) = each(%db_hash))
#        { print "[$key]: {$val}\n"; }

print Dumper \%db_hash;

my $search="mykey.1\0";
print "ONLY $search\n";
my $value = $db_hash{"$search"};
print "Value: $value\n" unless $value;

result :
$VAR1 = {
          "mykey.1\0" => "myVal1;myVal-1\0",
          "mykey.2\0" => "myval2\0"
        };
ONLY mykey.1

No value return so $value seems to be null.

Additionnal info
@clamp if I remove "unless $value" it's working.
I need to add \0 at the end of the key !

You say you have a hash with a specific key that you got from a database with a certain module. It looks like you do have that key, and it doesn't exist when you try to extract it. That means your data is broken somehow. Without further test data, nothing more can be done, and the question can be closed as "Need more debugging details". I would try use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper \%db_hash; and check for non-printable characters in the key.

How was the database populated?

print "Value: $value\n" unless $value; won’t print if $value is true

unless is short for if not, so it only prints if $value is false. Your fields seem to be ending with a null character, which is likely a setting in that database. You may be extracting your data in the wrong way. You should include information about the database in your question.

Found a solution in the documentation: https://metacpan.org/pod/DB_File#An-Example-the-NULL-termination-problem.

@TLP I'm using postmap to generate the DB. postmap is a C program that explain why I have null terminaison. Your solution is perfectely working. Thks a lot for you help.

@YannickMOLINET If you want, you can answer your own question with the solution you found that is working for you. Then mark the question as solved by clicking the checkmark

As mentionned in my initial question, I'm using postmap to generate the db files.
As mentionned here : https://metacpan.org/pod/DB_File#An-Example-the-NULL-termination-problem. C program add a NULL Termination at the end of the string (key and value).
Postmap is written in C so it add a NULL Terminaison.
So, my problem is due to my need to read a database generate by a C program with perl
To be able to match correctly the key, it's need to add "\0" add the end of the key
$db_hash{"$search\0"}

and not
$db_hash{"$search"}

